# Relación entre un Servlet y Spring

Tags: java, spring

Es necesario dominar la programación de Servlet Java para poder programar aplicaciones web con frameworks como Spring, ¿Spring utiliza los servlets? o son dos cosas que no tienen nada que ver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es obligatorio que seas un Experto en desarrollo web usando Servlets, Jsp (jstl), pero si debes tener un conocimiento mínimo de ello ya que son lo esencial ya que  muchos Frameworks MVC `implementan internamente Servlets`.

**¿FrameWorks?**

> Spring

- Frameworks como Spring se desarrollan en la parte superior de Servlet
  / JSP.
- Están destinados a eliminar duplicidad de código. Los Frameworks se
  basan en patrones de diseño y en soluciones reutilizables  a 
  problemas comunes.
- Ayudan a acelerar el desarrollo proporcionando una solución general a
  problemas comúnmente conocidos. (Por ejemplo, validación de
  formularios, REST, pruebas, inyección de dependencia, etc.)
- Cuando está desarrollando una aplicación empresarial de gran escala y
  tiene varios desarrolladores trabajando en ella, definitivamente
  necesita una cierta uniformidad en el proyecto / código / estructura
  que cada desarrollador está escribiendo. Las imposiciones forzadas
  externamente no son confiables, pero cuando se construyen ayudan a
  hacer que el proyecto sea fácil de mantener, escalable y fácil para
  que la gente nueva pueda ser productiva con ella en poco tiempo.(Cosa
  que usando servlets 100% sería una labor titanica)

Los `Servlets`se basan en una API de bajo nivel para gestionar solicitudes y respuestas. Los Framework web como Spring MVC están diseñados para facilitar la creación de aplicaciones web que gestionan solicitudes y respuestas HTTP. La mayoría de los frameworks web Java, incluyendo Spring MVC, `usan Servlets detrás (ServeletDispatcher)`.

**¿ Los principios?**

> Sevlets:

Puedes utilizar Servlets para escribir una aplicación web, pero tendrías que manejar todos los detalles manualmente. Obtendrás muy poca ayuda con cosas típicas de la red como validación, REST, request / response body para JSON, vinculación de formularios, etc. Terminarás escribiendo mucho código de utilidad para soportar Tu aplicación web.

Los Frameworks web, por otro lado, están diseñados para hacer todo esto simple.  Spring MVC, no se molestó en manejar manualmente la solicitud y la respuesta, aunque todavía puede obtener acceso a ellos si es necesario. ¿Quieres devolver JSON en Spring MVC? Simplemente agregue una anotación `@ResponseBody` y Spring lo añadirá. ¿Quieres URL RESTful? Fácil. ¿Validación de entrada? Pedazo de pastel. ¿Desea vincular datos de formulario a un objeto? Sencillo. Con servlets, tendrías que hacer todo esto manualmente.

> El uso de **servlets** sin procesar son una buena experiencia de
>   aprendizaje sin embargo. Realmente ayudan a aclarar cómo los
>   Frameworks  web hacen la vida más fácil!

**Mayor referencia:**

- [Spring MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)
- [¿Qué son los Servlets?](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafe.html)
- [Spring Framework](https://spring.io/)